# How is child a different width if it's "100%" or "inherit" from Parent?

Tags: css

How is it possible for a Child element, contained within a Parent, to be a different width than the parent, if
1) the Child's Width is 100%
2) the Child's Width is 'inherit' ?

Both of these are occurring to me. Very hard to put together a quick Fiddle as I'm dealing with a huge page.

Comment: This could be due to `padding`, `border`, or `margin`?

Comment: Could also be that your Child element has content with fixed size, one that causes it to overflow.

Comment: Just because you can't put together a *quick* fiddle doesn't mean you shouldn't provide a [mcve]. Take the time...do it right...we might wait.

Comment: Always be careful if you don't have any sort of reset styler included in your project as your browser usually applies styles by default. Try to use this little css file (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css) before you apply your styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inherit` does not necessarily inherit the actual width in pixels of the parent.
With `width:100%`, the width of the child can look like it's less than the parent's when the parent has a padding.

```css
div.parent {
  background:yellow; color:brown;
  padding:0 1em;
  width:20em;
}

div.child {
  background:brown; color:yellow;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  This is the parent
  <div class="child">
    This is the child
  </div>
</div>
```

And if a block parent with `width:auto` has an inline-block child with `width:inherit`, the child's width will be `auto`, which still makes it as wide as its contents, rather than the width of the parent.

```css
div.parent {
  background:yellow; color:brown;
}

div.child {
  background:brown; color:yellow;
  width:inherit;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  The parent (full width of the window)<br>
  <div class="child">
    The child (only as wide as its contents)
  </div>
</div>
```